How to determine the correct GPIO chip for libgpiod?
I am writing software that needs to control some of the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins.
The Internet tells me that sysfs is deprecated and anyhow doesn't work on the Raspberry Pi 5. Apparently the "correct" solution is to use libgpiod.
The libgpiod documentation tells me that the first step is to call gpio_chip_open and pass the path and filename of a gpio chip device.
However, I can find no explanation as to how one is to know the correct filename to use. On the Raspberry Pi 5, at this moment in time, it is apparently "/dev/gpiochip4"; but it will almost certainly be something else on a Pi 4, for instance. And my software has to work on all Pis.
In the shell, I can invoke gpiofind GPIO22 and get the chip name and gpio index for GPIO 22 on the standard header. But in C++ or Python, there is no obvious way to determine this.
Unless the official wisdom is that I should execute a shell command from C++ and capture its output? Surely not...

strace gpiofind GPIO22 is pretty interesting in this case since it contains the relevant syscalls which can be made directly from C++.

You can also use ioctl for GPIO programming (which seems to be faster if a little cryptic to code). The comment by @goldilocks indicates this is used by gpiofind to get gpiochip info.

I've closed this question because it is obviously impossible to resolve it without aburdist bickering.  There is more than enough information here already if anyone cares to bother reading it with a clear head.

It was a minor change to my Pi revision code to get processor and thus determine correct gpiochip which I include for the benefit of others encountering problems.
The code to determine gpiochip is independent of any other libraries so could easily be included in any program requiring it.
Below I have listed c & python versions of my revision code and examples of a modification to a couple of simple lgpio examples
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""
Raspberry Pi Processor & Type
"""
import sys
# 2024-07-13

def get_revision():
    """
    Returns Raspberry Pi Revision Code
    """
    with open("/proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision", "rb") as fp:
        return int.from_bytes(fp.read(4), 'big')

def processor():
    """
    Raspberry Pi SOC
    returns
        0: BCM2835
        1: BCM2836
        2: BCM2837
        3: BCM2711
        4: BCM2712
    """
    return int((get_revision()>>12)&7)

def type():
    """
    Raspberry Pi Type
    returns
    0: A
    1: B
    2: A+
    3: B+
    4: 2B
    6: CM1
    8: 3B
    9: Zero
    a: CM3
    c: Zero W
    d: 3B+
    e: 3A+
    10: CM3+
    11: 4B
    12: Zero 2 W
    13: 400
    14: CM4
    15: CM4S
    17: 5
    """
    return int((get_revision()>>4)&0xff)

def main():
    print(f"{get_revision():08x}")
    print(f"{processor()}")
    print(f"{type():02x}")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
// Raspberry Pi Revision, Processor & Type
// 2024-07-13

unsigned get_revision(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  uint32_t n = 0;

  if ((fp = fopen("/proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision", "r"))) {
    if (fread(&n, sizeof(n), 1, fp) != 1) {
      fclose(fp);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return ntohl(n);
}

unsigned processor(void) {
     return (get_revision()>>12)&7;
}

unsigned type(void) {
    return (get_revision()>>4)&0xff;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Version =\t%08x\n", get_revision());
  printf("Processor =\t%d\n", processor());
  printf("Type =\t\t%02x\n", type());
  return 0;
}

#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""
This program toggles a GPIO pin and measures rate.
Using lgpio Python Interface
"""
# 2024-04-02
# 2024-04-24    commas in number
# 2024-07-13  modified for Pi5/BCBM2712

import lgpio
import time
gpiochip = 0
SigOUT = 12
LOOPS = 20000

def get_revision():
    """
    Returns Raspberry Pi Revision Code
    """
    with open("/proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision", "rb") as fp:
        return int.from_bytes(fp.read(4), 'big')

def processor():
    """
    Raspberry Pi SOC
    returns
        0: BCM2835
        1: BCM2836
        2: BCM2837
        3: BCM2711
        4: BCM2712
    """
    return int((get_revision()>>12)&7)

if(processor()==4):
    gpiochip = 4

h = lgpio.gpiochip_open(gpiochip)
if h < 0:
   print('open error')

lgpio.gpio_claim_output(h, SigOUT)

t0 = time.time()

for i in range(LOOPS):
    lgpio.gpio_write(h, SigOUT, 1)
    lgpio.gpio_write(h, SigOUT, 0)

t1 = time.time()
nloops = (1.0 * LOOPS) / (t1 - t0)

print(f"lgpio Python\t{nloops:10,.0f} toggles per second")
lgpio.gpio_free(h, SigOUT)


/*
bench.c
This program toggles a GPIO pin and measures rate.
Using lgpio C API

gcc -Wall -o bench-lgpio bench-lgpio.c -llgpio

*/
// 2024-04-24   commas in number
// 2024-07-13 Support for Pi5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <lgpio.h>

#define LFLAGS 0

#define SigOUT 12
#define LOOPS 20000

unsigned get_revision(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  uint32_t n = 0;

  if ((fp = fopen("/proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision", "r"))) {
    if (fread(&n, sizeof(n), 1, fp) != 1) {
      fclose(fp);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return ntohl(n);
}

unsigned processor(void) {
     return (get_revision()>>12)&7;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int h;
  int i;
  double t0, t1;
  int status;
  
    if(processor()==4)
            h = lgGpiochipOpen(4);
    else
            h = lgGpiochipOpen(0);

  if (h >= 0) {
    if ((status = lgGpioClaimOutput(h, LFLAGS, SigOUT, 0)) == LG_OKAY) {
      t0 = lguTime();

      for (i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        lgGpioWrite(h, SigOUT, 0);
        lgGpioWrite(h, SigOUT, 1);
      }

      t1 = lguTime();

            int nloops = (1.0 * LOOPS) / (t1 - t0);
            setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
            printf("lgpio\tC\t%'10d toggles per second\n", nloops);
    } else {
      printf("lgGpioClaimSigOUTput FAILED on Pin %d\n", SigOUT);
      lgLineInfo_t lInfo;

      status = lgGpioGetLineInfo(h, SigOUT, &lInfo);

      if (status == LG_OKAY) {
        if (lInfo.lFlags & 1) {
          printf("GPIO in use by the kernel ");
          printf("name=%s  user=%s\n", lInfo.name, lInfo.user);
        }
      }
    }
        lgGpioFree(h, SigOUT);
    lgGpiochipClose(h);
  } else
    printf("Unable to open gpiochip 0\n");
}


Interesting. Thank you for that. And these /proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision numbers are guaranteed to (a) be there and (b) not change for a given model of Pi, even when new firmware comes out? I'm concerned by Kent's implication that the gpiochip number might change on the Pi 5 on a whim, without warning. So no matter how I detect the model (numerically like your example, or textually by parsing /proc/cpuinfo), perfectly working code could suddenly fail.

On my Pi 5, your Python get_revision() function returns 23, which isn't in your list of valid values. Why is this? get_revision() returns 13648240. cat /proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision | hexdump -C prints the bytes 00 d0 41 70.

The return should be 0x17 -  taken as is from   Raspberry Pi Ltd. documentation which is 23 decimal. The listed values are HEX (as should be obvious from the code if you ran the first 2 programs) but you could use decimal.

NOTE the processor function returns 4 so you don't need to fiddle with decoding the revision code or worry about any new Pi variants using the same chip.

Ah, that makes more sense. I had not noticed your list of model numbers was in hex. Again thank you for the help.

'Apparently the "correct" solution is to use libgpiod'; this may be true BUT the version in Debian & Raspberry Pi OS is deprecated, at least 3 years old, has minimal documentation and no examples.
It does work if you are prepared to put in the work or install an up-to-date version.
The recommended Raspberry Pi OS solution for Python is gpiozero which uses lgpio which has c & python support and is reasonably documented and has examples. There is no need to worry about which gpiochip to use in gpiozero as these use normal BCM numbering.
At the moment if using Pi5/BCM2712 you need to use gpiochip4, but this may change in the future to gpiochip0 like all earlier models.
You can access the Revision Code to determine the Pi Model. This is easy to access in c at /proc/device-tree/system/linux,revision

Please confirm: All Pis up to and including the Pi 4 use gpiochip0 for the GPIOs? And the Pi 5 uses gpiochip4? And those numbers absolutely will not change in those models of Pi, even with firmware updates?

You say it "may change in the future" – I assume you mean for the Pi 6 or something? The existing Pis can be relied upon to keep their current numbering?

All Pi up to Pi3 had the same peripheral, the Pi4 introduced a few more features but was backward compatible. I have heard that Raspberry Pi Ltd. were planning to fix the mess in BCM2712 but I have also heard they were planning to implement libgpiod v2 and have no inside information. I wouldn't count on anything - they seem to have just dumped most of the documentation on anything pre Bookworm. This is nothing to do with actual hardware (I assume RP1 will not change - only the software.)  Not that long ago they actually got around to fixing the GPIO drivers to work with libgpiod.
